# Reactjs, can't getelementbyid when the elem is inside a map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm facing a problem with reactjs.

I need to compare screen height with a div in order to set the max-width of it.

No problem with the screen size, the problem is that the div I want to check is inside a map. Thus, this line always return null:

```
componentDidMount() {
    test2 = document.getElementById("coucou");
    console.log(test2);
}
```

which refers to:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.data.map((value, i) => {
        return (
          <div key={i}>
            {
              this.state.activeIndex === 0 ?
                  <div id="coucou" style={{width: '75%', margin: '0 auto'}}>
                      <img 
                          className={"image-detail"}
                          style={{maxWidth: '80%', borderRadius: '12px'}} 
                          src={imgBaseUrl + value['mainImage']}
                      />
                  </div>
            }
          </div>
        );
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

So, I can't access the id nor the class of the div.

Any idea why? And how could I have access to those elements?

Ps: the code showing is a part of the whole, the map deals with other condition. Nevertheless, I checked it, the id is unique to this div / image. 
But the problem is the same with a `getElementsByClass => null`

Comment: _“Any idea why?”_ – because the element needs to be part of the DOM to be selectable via `document.getElementById`.

Comment: Did you try it in componentDidMount()?

Comment: My bad Boky, I didn't wrote it but yes, it comes from componentDidMount()!

Comment: Also, why not use a react ref instead of an ID?

Answer (score 1):

React works by working on a "virtual" DOM before rendering to the real DOM, so unless your test statements are executed *after* a call to `ReactDOM.render`, the result is to be expected, the element is still in React's virtual DOM.

Assuming you placed the test code in the correct place, in [`.componentDidMount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) for instance, have you tried logging `this.props.data` directly? It may simply be empty in your case.

Moreover there's also a little problem with your code since `Array#map` produces an array of values, there can be multiple `div`s with the `id` "coucou", and that [isn't valid HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).

Comment: You can as well take the other part of what I said, and replace id by className ;)
this.props.data is indeed empty.
How would you execute a call after the render()? I thought it was the componentDidMount() purpose

Comment: It is indeed. I didn't see your precision in your question comments at the time.

Answer (score 0):

If there a reason why you are not following best practice and using a [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)?

```
return (
  <div>
    {this.props.data.map((value, i) => {
      return (
        <div key={i}>
          {
            this.state.activeIndex === 0 ?
                <div ref={n => (this.coucouRef = n)} style={{width: '75%', margin: '0 auto'}}>
                    <img 
                        className="image-detail"
                        style={{maxWidth: '80%', borderRadius: '12px'}} 
                        src={imgBaseUrl + value['mainImage']}
                    />
                </div>
          }
        </div>
      );
    }
  </div>
);
```

And access via `this.coucouRef`.

Also note that you don't need to wrap static strings in braces - `className="image-detail"` will do.

Also, it is bad practice to assign an array index as the key in your loop - try and use something unique to that item, such as an ID which does not change according to the order the array is in.

Comment: Hey Dominic! Thank you so much. As I'm working alone I highly appreciate this kind of feedback.
The reason I didn't use ref is because I have the same result. So right now I tried the same ref syntaxe as the one you propose here.. Calling it then in componentDidMount or in another "callback" function (as described on fb doc) but I keep having an undefined on this.coucouRef.